# How to chain get and map the result with lodash?

Tags: lodash

I've got a list I'm trying to pull an object from using _.get but following that selection I need to loop over the object to create a new property. So far I've been successful using a combination of _.get and _.map as shown below but I'm hoping I can use _.chain in some way.

```
var selected = _.get(results, selectedId);
return _.map([selected], result => {
  var reviews = result.reviews.map(review => {
    var reviewed = review.userId === authenticatedUserId;
    return _.extend({}, review, {reviewed: reviewed});
  });
  return _.extend({}, result, {reviews: reviews});
})[0];
```

Is it possible to do a transform like this using something other than map (as map required me to break this up/ creating an array with a solo item inside it). Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see that you're creating unnecessary [map()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#map) calls, you can simply reduce all those work into something like this:

```
var output = {
  reviews: _.map(results[selectedId], function(review) {
    return _.defaults({
      reviewed: review.userId === authenticatedUserId
    }, review);
  })
};
```

The [defaults()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#defaults) method is similar to [extend()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#assignIn) except once a property is set, additional values of the same property are ignored.

```js
var selectedId = 1;
var authenticatedUserId = 1;

var results = {
  1: [
    { userId: 1, text: 'hello' },
    { userId: 2, text: 'hey' },
    
    { userId: 1, text: 'world?' },
    { userId: 2, text: 'nah' },
   ]
};

var output = {
  reviews: _.map(results[selectedId], function(review) {
    return _.defaults({
      reviewed: review.userId === authenticatedUserId
    }, review);
  })
};

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(output, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is exactly the type of lodash education I was looking for! thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: @ToranBillups I edited the answer, I switched the arguments in the _.defaults() call, that should be the correct arrangement since we don't want the object to mutate, and it would persist the value in the first argument even if the `review` object contains the `reviewed` property.